# API GATEWAY not retreiving request body

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to create a POST endpoint in API gateway with request body in application/json type. Now, in input body mapping template, I want to check if the input is there and if the required fields are present or not. I tried getting input body using $input.body and also tried $input.json('$') and $input.path('$'). Nothing works, input body is always empty, although the $input.body == "" check always returns false. But in the test logs i can see that the body is passed through. I'm using Mock as integration type. What can be an issue?

Comment: I think the following article summarize your problem and needs: https://itnext.io/how-to-validate-http-requests-before-they-reach-lambda-2fff68bfe93b

Comment: @SándorBakos This uses Lambad, I am using MOCK integration...But The logs say Request body as empty after Transformation...Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the answer to this is that, actually the reponse body isn't accessible when we use `MOCK` integration as provided by AWS, but we can still access body using a hacky method by:
First, in the integration request mapping template you store the body in a path parameter.

```
#set($context.requestOverride.path.body = $input.body)
{
  "statusCode": 200,
}
```

Then, in the integration response mapping template you fetch it back and return it.

```
#set($body = $context.requestOverride.path.body)
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": $body,
}
```

And then to parse it:

```
$util.parseJson($body).varName
```